# Restrict OpenFileDialog to access only network files

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, openfiledialog

I want to customize my **OpenFileDialog** a bit so that it can **only access one of my network PC (tsclient)** and not access my local drives and downloads folder.

I have no idea to achieve this. So, i am using a **temporary alternative** which sets the by default location to network but does not block local resource usage.

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts);
```

Can anyone tell me how to block local resource usage but let the network resources accessable?

Comment: Do you want the `restriction` to be done before the user selects the folder or after the user selects it?

Comment: I think it's not possible directly. Please check following link.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae322891-fd55-4027-ae4f-53100ae32852/openfiledialog-restrict-directory-browsing?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: You can stop user after user press OK. but i think you want to stop directory browsing. which can not be accomplished easily i think.

Comment: can you tell me how to stop as the user clicks "OK" on any local resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want you can do **after** the user clicks "OK/Open" to any of the file is to check the selected `filepath` (or `FileName`).

If the `filepath` is not the network `filepath`, you should reject it and ask the user to repeat its choice.

For instance, if `Z:\` is your network folder, then you can code something like this,

```
bool accepted;
do {
    accepted = false;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        accepted = ofd.FileName.Substring(0, 3) == "Z:\\"; //change this to your network folder
        if (accepted) {
            //accepted network folder, do something
        } else {
            //accepted network folder, gives warning with message box
        }
    } else if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) {
        accepted = true; //if the user chooses cancel, he can go out of the loop
    }
} while (!accepted); //prevents unaccepted answer
```

Edit:

1. The above example is limited only to give the main idea that **you could check what `filepath` is selected by the user before approving it**. It is understood that `Z:\` may not always be where the network folder is.
2. In case you need more dynamic way to determine whether a drive is in the network or not, I recommend you to look at [DriveInfo.DriveType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx).
3. In case you need even more robust way for checking, you could create client-specific list of accessible folders in one of your newly-defined config file.
4. And in case you have multiple users having different privileges, you will need to check the privileges of the users together with the folder accessed before determining whether the user can proceed using the file or not.
5. In **all** cases, they share the same main idea: *the user input must be first accepted before the user can proceed*. This main idea is the one that is demonstrated in my example above.

Hope it may clarify

Comment: this solution is not viable as you mention the drive specifically "Z" a computer might have a drive "E" as shared drive. How can i recognize that the folder is a local resource or network resource.

Comment: The example above is just to give you the idea. For argument's sake, we might even need to implement this in bigger scale. In such scenario I might do some other things like having client-specific `config file` which contains the list of accessible network folders for them (for it is possible that not all network folders are accessible to any users). If you need list of strings instead of simply `Z:\\`` as the qualifier, you can change  the the simple condition from `.Substring` to something like List.Contains or even using more complicated LINQ lambda expressions. But the idea here is:

Comment: To check whether that folder is acceptable for the user to access or not. What do we mean by acceptable and not acceptable are adjustable, depending on the situation. Thus, the condition I put above `Z:\\`` should not be taken literally. You may change the condition the way you want. As long as it is not accepted, you repeat the process. I apologize for the unintentional misdirection if my example seems too simple for you.